# High FPS Camera for OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, openframeworks

I'm tracking an object which I expect to move at a maximum speed of 10m/s using its colour.

I'm having a hard time finding a camera which will work at around 200fps. I'll be using a very low resolution (640x360) for faster processing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: This is the only one I've found so far and I'm not convinced it supports live streaming. Sony Action Cam AS100V (H.264 - 800 x 480 - 240 fps) - https://www.cnet.com/products/sony-action-cam-as100v/specs/

Comment: The speed of the object is irrelevant without knowing the focal length of the lens and its distance from the object. If your images are RGB colour and 640x360 minimum, you will need 138MB/s of bandwidth at 200fps uncompressed, so you are beyond double the performance of USB2. Have you maybe considered 8 synchronised Raspberry Pis or somesuch - may be viable and cheaper than a monster fast camera...

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a hardware problem, and, probably, it is somewhat misfit to StackOverflow (meaning that you could probably get more answers somewhere like [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)). Unfortunately, you didn't mention your requirements for tracking accuracy, the scale of the scene and so on, so it is hard to suggest an algorithmic workaround (e.g. usage of a low-fps camera and interpolating the object's location between the frame gaps).

Having said that, you could consider [Basler industrial cameras](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/). Namely, take a look at their [ace series](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/cameras/area-scan-cameras/ace) which include cameras with crazy framerates like 203 fps, 376 fps, 511 fps, and even 751 fps. Note the interfaces they use (USB 3.0, GigE, Camera Link). You will also need to buy lens for them separately. There is a tool on their website to select the right focal length of lenses based on camera and shooting distance.

While the acquired camera solution will be solid, you will need to take care of the hardware issues (such as interfaces), and, surely, pay a higher price than for a common webcam.  On the other hand, I don't think the required fps can be found among common webcams.